# Getting nAudio WAV to MP3 muLaw error during conversion

Tags: naudio

I am grabbing a WAV file (successfully) via a web service and am able to play it on my Windows 7 machine.  Now I need to grab that same WAV file and convert it to an MP3 file.  This is failing.  I have tried retrieving the file as a WAV (above) then using --

WaveStream PCMStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader);

to convert this muLaw to PCM.

This is failing with the attached error.  I have tried converting directly using LameMP3FileWriter but this too fails telling me that the "muLaw format cannot be converted to MP3.

What am I missing?
CODER SNIPPET

```
 private void WriteMP3(string iNum, string CallId)
    {
        //construct the replay URL using the iNum
        string url = "http://" + _VerintServer + "/searchapi?command=replay&id=" + iNum;

        // name the new mp3 file
        string mp3File =_basePath + "mp3\\" + CallId + ".mp3";
        string tempWav = _basePath + "mp3\\" + CallId + ".wav";
        string tempPCM = _basePath + "mp3\\" + CallId + "_PCM.wav";

        //issue the web service request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

        //retrieve the content type as raw PCM (.wav)
        request.ContentType = "audio/wav";

        //encode and include the basic authentication credentials
        string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(_username + ":" + _password));
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

        //retrieve the response
        HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        //copy the stream of bytes to the local directory using the CallId as the file name
        if (request.HaveResponse)
        {
            //create a temporary wav file 
            using (var receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var PStream = new FileStream(tempWav, FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    receiveStream.CopyTo(PStream);
                }
            }

            WaveToPCM(tempWav, tempPCM);
            WaveToMP3(tempPCM, mp3File, 128);
        }
        return;
    }

    //Convert muLaw WAV to PCM
    private void WaveToPCM(string waveFileName, string pcmFileName)
    {
        using (var reader = new CueWaveFileReader(waveFileName))
        {
            WaveStream PCMStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader);
            using (var PStream = new FileStream(pcmFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
               PCMStream.CopyTo(PStream);
            }            
        }           
        return;
    }

    // Convert WAV to MP3 using libmp3lame library
    public void WaveToMP3(string waveFileName, string mp3FileName, int bitRate = 128)
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(waveFileName))
        using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3FileName, reader.WaveFormat, bitRate))
            reader.CopyTo(writer);
    }
```

STACK TRACE:

> {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header","ExceptionType":"System.FormatException","StackTrace":"   at NAudio.FileFormats.Wav.WaveFileChunkReader.ReadRiffHeader(BinaryReader br)\r\n   at NAudio.FileFormats.Wav.WaveFileChunkReader.ReadWaveHeader(Stream stream)\r\n   at NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader..ctor(Stream inputStream)\r\n   at NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader..ctor(String waveFile)\r\n   at DataServices.Controllers.RecordingsController.WaveToMP3(String waveFileName, String mp3FileName, Int32 bitRate) in c:\Codebank\DataAccess\DataServices\Controllers\RecordingsController.cs:line 179\r\n   at DataServices.Controllers.RecordingsController.WriteMP3(String iNum,

Comment: EDIT:  The code snippet has a typo.  "CueWaveFileReader" is actually "WaveFileReader" but the same "Not a WAVE file error..." is being thrown.

Comment: EDIT:When I bypass the WAV to PCM converter I get the following error:

Comment: {"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Unsupported encoding format MuLaw\r\nParameter name: format","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":"   at NAudio.Lame.LameMP3FileWriter..ctor(Stream outStream, WaveFormat format, Int32 bitRate)\r\n   at NAudio.Lame.LameMP3FileWriter..ctor(String outFileName, WaveFormat format, Int32 bitRate)\r\n   at DataServices.Controllers.RecordingsController.WaveToMP3(String waveFileName, String mp3FileName, Int32 bitRate) in c:\\Codebank\\DataAccess\\DataServices\\Controllers\\RecordingsController.cs:line 179\r\n   at

Answer (score 1):

In your `WaveToPcm` function you are simply writing the raw samples to a file. You need to use `WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile` passing in `PCMStream` to make the 16 bit PCM WAV file that you can pass to the LAME MP3 Writer

Comment: Is this correct?  I am concerned about your admonition about the "Waveprovider must return 0..."

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mark.  I am now successfully converting the muLaw encoded WAV file to raw PCM as noted in the code below.

```
        //Convert muLaw WAV to PCM
    private void WaveToPCM(string waveFileName, string pcmFileName)
    {
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(waveFileName))
        {

           WaveStream PCMStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader);
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(pcmFileName, PCMStream);        
        }           
        return;
    }
```